# Having trouble with a Lim (infinity-infinity)

Tags: limits

so I am learning about Limits at the moment and I am having some trouble with this Lim..

$\lim_{x\to ∞}=\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{16x^3+4x-1}-\sqrt{16x^3+3}) $

I just can't get the right answer, which is $ \frac 12 $ ,

I know how to do the -> $\lim_{x\to ∞}=(\sqrt{16x^3+4x-1}-\sqrt{16x^3+3}) $

but I can't do the exact lim with square root from x in front... I just don't know what to do with it, tried everything and looked everywhere but I can't even find one example with this particular setup...
help ? anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribute the $\sqrt x$: $$\sqrt a(\sqrt b - \sqrt c) = \sqrt a\sqrt b - \sqrt a \sqrt c = \sqrt {ab} - \sqrt{ac}$$

In terms of your limit:
$$\lim_{x\to ∞}=\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{16x^3+4x-1}-\sqrt{16x^3+3}) = \lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x(16x^3+4x-1)}-\sqrt{x(16x^3+3)})$$

Now evaluate the limit as you know how to do: by multiplying the function by $\dfrac{\text{conjugate}}{\text{conjugate}}$

Comment: Thanks , helped a lot, got my answer ;)

Comment: Great! You're welcome of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Use these equalities:
$$\sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}\quad\text{and}\quad a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $\frac1x=h,$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt x(\sqrt{16x^3+4x-1}-\sqrt{16x^3+3}) $$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{16+4h^2-h^3}-\sqrt{16+3h^3}}{h^2} $$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(16+4h^2-h^3)-(16+3h^3)}{h^2(\sqrt{16+4h^2-h^3}+\sqrt{16+3h^3})} $$

$$=4\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^2(1-h)}{h^2(\sqrt{16+4h^2-h^3}+\sqrt{16+3h^3})}$$

$$=4\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-h}{(\sqrt{16+4h^2-h^3}+\sqrt{16+3h^3})}\text{ as }h\ne0 \text{ as }h\to0$$

$$=\frac4{\sqrt{16}+\sqrt{16}}$$