# Limit of ($\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}$) as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been stuck on this one problem for 3 days now, I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

The problem is asking for the $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}) $$

Every time I attempt this problem, I can never get rid of infinity in the numerator without making the denominator zero. How can I do this problem?

Comment: You could also, after multiplying and dividing by the conjugate, use L'Hôpital's rule to analyze the denominator. You find that this limit behaves as the inverse of its conjugate, which tends to one-half as $x$ goes to infinity. A more general analysis may also be conceived of this way, if you make some assumptions about the coefficients.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564132/having-trouble-with-a-lim-infinity-infinity/564234#564234

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 +ax} - \sqrt{x^2 +bx}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62418/201168) (with $a=8$ and $b=7$). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}={({\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x})(\sqrt{x^2+8x}+\sqrt{x^2+7x})}\over{\sqrt{x^2+8x}+\sqrt{x^2+7x}}}={x\over {\mid x\mid\sqrt{1+8/x}+\mid x\mid \sqrt{1+7/x}}}$

${1\over {\sqrt{1+8/x}+ \sqrt{1+7/x}}}$ if $x>0$ and

${-1\over {\sqrt{1+8/x}+ \sqrt{1+7/x}}}$ if $x<0$

Answer (score 1):

You want
$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x})
$.

For reals $a$ and $b$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{x^2+bx}
&=(\sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{x^2+bx})\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{x^2+ax}-\sqrt{x^2+bx})(\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx})}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
&=\dfrac{(x^2+ax)-(x^2+bx)}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
&=\dfrac{ax-bx}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
&=\dfrac{x(a-b)}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+\sqrt{x^2+bx}}\\
&=\dfrac{a-b}{\sqrt{1+a/x}+\sqrt{1+b/x}}\\
&\to \dfrac{a-b}{2} \text{ as } x \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

The result is the same
if the expression is
$\sqrt{x^2+ax+c}-\sqrt{x^2+bx+d}
$.

Comment: You forgot to divide by 2 ( $=\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}$ ) when calculating the limit.

Comment: Thanks. Another careless error. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it.

Considering that $x\to\infty$ $$\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}=x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 8x}-\sqrt{1+\frac 7x} \right)$$ Now, using Taylor for small $y$ $$\sqrt{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ make $y=\frac 8x$ in the first radical and $y=\frac 7x$ in the second radical to get $$\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}=x\left(\left(1+\frac{4}{x}-\frac{8}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)  \right)-\left(1+\frac{7}{2 x}-\frac{49}{8 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)\right)$$ After simplification $$\sqrt{x^2+8x}-\sqrt{x^2+7x}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{15}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general as Marty Cohen did in his answer, doing the same, we should get

$$\sqrt{x^2+ax+c}-\sqrt{x^2+bx+d}=\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{-a^2+4 b+c^2-4 d}{8 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: You mean ${a-b\over 2}$? I edited. I think that for any limit one should try to go through the asymptotic series to see the way the limit is approached

Comment: @marwalix. I thought I typed that ... but I certainly missed something ! Thanks for editing. Cheers.